# ViewData filed in the Schema.xml is not defined in the JSLink script

Tags: list-view, jslink, schema

I have defined a site column which is rendered based on another column's information. Since I am not going to show that other column I define it in like:

```
    <ViewData>
      <FieldRef Name="MatterRagStatus" />
    </ViewData>
```

The column which I am going to show in the list view is defined like:

```
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="MatterIndicator" />
</ViewFields>
```

I have defined the JSLink where I defined this field in site columns:

```
<Field ID="{A5AE3A8A-E42A-4A87-9D7F-09E104FED180}"
     Name="MatterIndicator"
     StaticName="MatterIndicator"
     DisplayName="Indicator"
     Description="The column calculate matter status"
     Type="Text"
     ShowInEditForm="FALSE"
     ShowInNewForm="FALSE"
     ShowInListSettings="FALSE"
     Overwrite="TRUE"
     JSLink="~site/Scripts/MatterIndicator.js"
     Group="Evershed Site Columns">
<Default>•</Default>
```

here is my JSLink code:

```
(function () {
var hiddenFiledContext = {};
hiddenFiledContext.Templates = {};
hiddenFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
    "MatterIndicator": {
        "View": IndicatorOverrideFun,
        "DisplayForm": IndicatorOverrideFun,
        "EditForm": IndicatorOverrideFun,
        "NewForm": IndicatorOverrideFun
        },
};
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(hiddenFiledContext);})();
function IndicatorOverrideFun(ctx) {
try {
    if (ctx.CurrentItem.MatterRagStatus == "1-Red")
        return "<span style='font-size: 300%; line-height: 10%;color: #FF0000;'>•</span>";
    else if (ctx.CurrentItem.MatterRagStatus == "2-Amber")
        return "<span style='font-size: 300%; line-height: 10%;color: #FFBF00;'>•</span>";
    else
        return "<span style='font-size: 300%; line-height: 10%;color: #00FF00;'>•</span>";
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return "";
}
}
```

When the page was being loaded I inspected the JSLink and the context object(ctx) had value but the field in ViewData was missing. I wonder what might be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSlink has one nasty side-effect.

- Only the Fields **included in the View** are included in the ctx Object

In your use case I *think* you are mis-interpreting CSR/JSlink, there is no need to create a second MatterIndicator Field.
The whole point of CSR is that you override **the display** of the original MatterRagStatus Field.

If you do want separate field you either have to go get the missing data yourself with some 10 lines of Javascript I can not produce of the top of my head.

Or you can ditch JSlink and stuff this Formula in a Calculated Column (and set the datatype to Number)

```
="<span style=""font-size:300%;line-height:10%;"
&"color:#" 
& CHOOSE( LEFT( [MatterRagStatus] , 1) , "F00" , "FFBF00" , "0F0" )
&";"">•</span>"
```

- You can reference all columns, even those not in the View.
- It will work anywhere it is used **in a View**, that saves you from having to attach JSlinks all over the place.
- But it does **not** work for Forms, you have to use CSR there.

http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How explains all *Pros* and *Cons*